# How to extract text from site using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this html tag that i am trying to scrape

```
<span class="title NSNTitle">
      <small class="text-primary"><strong>
      ID 1040-KK-143-6964, 1040001436964
      </strong></small>
         <br>
      <small class="text-primary">
          MODIFICATION KIT,
     </small>
</span>
```

I use this code

```
   page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
   FSGcontainer = page_soup.find("h1", {"class": "nopad-top"}).find_all("small", {"class": "text-primary"})
   for subcontainer in FSGcontainer:
        FSGsubcard = subcontainer

        if FSGsubcard is not None:
            Nomenclature = FSGsubcard.text

            print(Nomenclature)
```

and I get this output

```
  NSN 1040-KK-143-6964, 1005009927288


                                    MODIFICATION KIT,
```

what I really want is the text "Modification kit,"
how can I capture just the text and not the IDs ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `select_one` together with a css selector that selects the second `small` element.

```
nomenclature = page_soup.find("h1", 
                             {"class": "nopad-top"}
                         ).select_one(
                             'small:nth-of-type(2)'
                         ).text.strip()
```

Comment: for some reason it prints three repetition of the out. i.e MODIFICATION KIT, (three times) do you know why?

Comment: Are you using this inside of a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will let you fetch the specific items you want.

```
for item in soup.find_all(class_="title"):
    text_item = item.find_all(class_="text-primary")[1].text
    print(text_item)
```

Result:

```
MODIFICATION KIT
```